# Data bind JSON model on an event

Tags: knockout.js

## [Here's a jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yvdgz/1/)

I've thrown together a jsFiddle to try and demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve (reflects third attempt so far).

---

I've just started playing around with [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) and I'm a little stumped. Here's what I *want* to do.

I have an asmx method that returns a JSON string, which is the following objects deserialized (most properties omitted for brevity):

```
class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

class Question
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I have a web page with `select` allowing the user to choose a `Template`. Once they've selected one, it goes off and calls the above method to return that template's configuration.

Initially I'm creating my JavaScript view model with a list of these templates, like this.

```
function viewModel(templates) {
    var self = this;
    self.templates = ko.observableArray(templates);
}

// this is just a $.ajax call to another asmx service that gets me 
// a JSON array of all templates
var templates = getTemplates();
var vm = ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(templates));
```

Then my markup uses this like so.

```
<select id="template" data-bind="foreach: templates">
    <option data-bind="text: Name, value: Id"></option>
</select>
```

All working fine so far, I guess my question is what is the *correct* way to return a template's configuration and store this in the view model, and display on the page?

**First attempt**

I've added a property `configuration` and a method `getConfiguration` to the view model and am invoking this by having `data-bind="change: getConfiguration` on the `select`.

```
function viewModel(templates) {
    var self = this;
    self.templates = ko.observableArray(templates);
    self.configuration = null;
    self.getConfiguration = function () {
        // calls the asmx web method, parses the returned JSON to an object
        // and then...
        self.configuration = $.parseJSON(data.d);
    };
}
```

But I'm not having much luck, can anyone give me a friendly nudge in the right direction? Appreciate any and all help as always.

**Second attempt**

Based on mael's answer below, I've tried to set `configuration` as an observable. Here's my markup (just trying to observe the template's name at the moment):

```
<div data-bind="if: configuration">
    <strong data-bind="text: configuration.Name"></strong>
</div>
```

And the `getConfiguration` method:

```
var config = $.parseJSON(data.d); // the ajax call to get the JSON
self.configuration = ko.observable(config);
```

I've also tried this with the mapping plugin:

```
self.configuration = ko.mapping.fromJS(config);
```

No luck though :s

**Third attempt**

I've decided to scrap the idea of storing the template list in my view model, and am just creating this list separately. The `ko.applyBindings` is now called on the `.change` event of my template list.

```
var viewModel = function (config) {
    var self = this;
    self.configuration = config;
}

$('#templates').unbind('change').on('change', function () {
    var id = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
    var config = getConfig(id); // calls my asmx method to get the config JSON
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(config));
});
```

Having much more success with this (although not sure whether I needed to remove the template list from the view model) - but now getting the following error [You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just getting a plain javascript object (which I think your template is), its properties do not become observable by knockout. You have to use knockout mapping plugin to make your template properties observable (see here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

You could also do your own javascript "Template" object. Something like that:

```
function Template(jsonTemplate) {
    this.id = ko.observable(jsonTemplate.id);
    //etc.
}
```

And then building Templates object from your JSON objects.

Comment: Updated the question with new attempts, no luck I'm afraid (providing I'm doing what you intended).

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Done, provided the link at the top.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Anyway, I tried to make it work. You should not use JQuery for event binding. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/TMnLh/1/

Comment: Sorry I thought I caught that in time. So, `ko.computed` seems to be exactly what I was after - thanks!!!